# How to rsync from remote properly?

Tags: rsync

I am trying to sync a remote directory to the local system directory `wimagasin` inside the htdocs on the mamp server.

I ran the command from my local htdocs directory:

```
rsync -avr deploy@wimagasin.se:public_html/wimagasin.se wimagasin
```

But when the command is run, the sync creates completely new directory `wimagasin.se` inside my local `wimagasin` directory. I am not sure what is the right way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just append a slash at the source:

```
rsync -avr deploy@wimagasin.se:public_html/wimagasin.se/ wimagasin
```

Comment: This is correct. The key thing to remember is that if you leave out the trailing slash of the source, the directory itself is copied to the target. If you include the slash the contents are copied but the directory itself won't be created.